# How to import NLP model (facebook bart large mnli model) in Julia?

Tags: python, nlp, julia, huggingface-transformers

I would like to seek help in importing the `bart-large-mnli` model for `zero-shot-classification` in Julia?

Reference to the model: https://metatext.io/models/facebook-bart-large-mnli

This is the python example which I want to port to Julia:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification",
                      model="facebook/bart-large-mnli")
sequence_to_classify = "one day I will see the world"
candidate_labels = ['travel', 'cooking', 'dancing']
classifier(sequence_to_classify, candidate_labels)
```

Expected Output:

```
{'sequence': 'one day I will see the world', 
 'labels': ['travel', 'dancing', 'cooking'], 
 'scores': [0.9938650727272034, 0.0032738070003688335, 0.002861041808500886]
}
```

Please advise or suggest a solution for this scenario.
Look forward to the responses. Thanks!

Comment: Is the output supposed to be a string?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure quite what your desired use case is, but if you want to just have access to the pretrained huggingface model output in your Julia code, you can use [PyCall.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl) to call that Python code and return the dictionary you're interested in.

That is, in Julia, run the python code in py"""..."""

```
julia> py"""
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification",
                      model="facebook/bart-large-mnli")
sequence_to_classify = "one day I will see the world"
candidate_labels = ['travel', 'cooking', 'dancing']
output = classifier(sequence_to_classify, candidate_labels)
"""
```

then the Python global variable `output` will be accessible with `py"output"` in Julia (the Python `dict` automatically converted to a Julia `Dict`), like

```
julia> py"output"
Dict{Any, Any} with 3 entries:
  "scores"   => [0.993865, 0.00327379, 0.00286104]
  "sequence" => "one day I will see the world"
  "labels"   => ["travel", "dancing", "cooking"]
```

you can also get it as a PyObject without the automatic type conversion, by putting `o` after the string:

```
julia> py"output"o
PyObject {
  'sequence': 'one day I will see the world', 
  'labels': ['travel', 'dancing', 'cooking'], 
  'scores': [0.9938650727272034, 0.0032737923320382833, 0.002861042506992817]
}
```

---

You could also get something similar by importing the python package `transformers` into Julia with PyCall's `pyimport()`, and

```
using PyCall
transformers = PyCall.pyimport("transformers")
classifier = transformers.pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model="facebook/bart-large-mnli")
sequence_to_classify = "one day I will see the world"
candidate_labels = ["travel", "cooking", "dancing"]
output = classifier(sequence_to_classify, candidate_labels)
```

now the Julia object `output` will be the Dict you want.

Comment: HI! What Python version are you using for this? When I call `classifier = transformers.pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model="facebook/bart-large-mnli")` I get: 
`ERROR: PyError (PyObject_GetAttrString) <class 'RuntimeError'>
RuntimeError("Failed to import transformers.pipelines because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):\n/home/dijkie/packages/julias/julia-1.8/bin/../lib/julia/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.30 not found (required by /home/dijkie/miniconda3/envs/ds/lib/python3.10/...`

Comment: That was a while ago, but I think I was using Python 3.10, as it seems you are.